# Oracle define Day, Month in table definition

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, create-table

In SQLServer, in a table definition, I can have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [DateTable] ( 
    [Daily_Date] [date] null,
    [DayPart] as (datepart(day,[Daily_Date])),
    [MonthPart] as (datepart(month,[Daily_Date]))
)
```

Is it possible to do the same in Oracle?  The following is not making it happy:

```
CREATE TABLE DateTable ( 
    Daily_Date Date null,
    DayPart as Extract (Day from Daily_Date)
    MonthPart Extract (Month from Daily_Date)
)
```

Comment: @SebastianBrosch - Please put that answer back - it has useful information for getting the month name, which I also need.

Comment: I can see Sebastian's answer, and while it is correct (I don't know why he deleted it), I don't see where it shows you how to get the month **name**. What do you mean by that? In any case, the month NAME is calculated as `TO_CHAR(Daily_Date, 'Mon'`)  (or `'Month'`)  for the short name (Jan, Feb etc.) or long name (January etc.) respectively. Actually the names will be in your session's date language; you can control that with a third argument in the `TO_CHAR` call - see the docs for it and for `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`.

Comment: @mathguy he just showed code that I hadn't seen before, that I expected I might be able to also use, since my example only showed part of what I was looking for.  Your comments are useful too.

Comment: The two extra things in his code were: (1) he showed the data type of the calculated columns, `INTEGER`. That is optional - Oracle determines the data type from the return data type of the function. (2) he showed the entirely optional boilerplate words `GENERATED ALWAYS` before the required keyword `AS`. That is just syntactical sugar - you can use that if you think it makes things clearer, but that's just about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DDL raises error:

```
ORA-02000: missing ( keyword
```

Parentheses are mandatory around the computation expression. The `as` keyword is also mandatory. Finally, you were missing a comma between the declaration of the second and third column.

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE DateTable ( 
    Daily_Date Date null,
    DayPart as (Extract(Day from Daily_Date)),
    MonthPart as (Extract(Month from Daily_Date))
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=87337c6d245487a2993cf81f340b418f)**